# Is there a PHP Doc syntax for "function modifies argument passed by reference"?

Tags: php, documentation

When writing a PHP doc for a function, if the function returns a value you'd write something like

`@return array $someArray An array of formatted dates`

But let's say that my function doesn't return a value but rather it modifies the original value that is passed as a reference something like:

```
   function formatDates(&$input_arr){
        /**
         * Formats an array of dates
         * @param array $input_arr An array of raw dates
         */
        array_walk_recursive($input_arr, 'formatDateFunction');
    }
```

This function modifies the input array.

I know it's obvious with the `&` in front of the parameter but return values are pretty obvious with `return` in front of them too, so I feel like there may be a standard for this?

Currently, I just mention it in the function description like:

```
        /**
         * Formats an array of dates, modifies original array
```

**Is there a commonly used way of stating that a function modifies the input value in the PHP docs? Or is it just normally left as implied?**

Comment: Yes, an ampersand, same as in the actual function/method definition itself `* @param array &$input_arr An array of raw dates`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like so

`* @param array &$array modified parameter array of dates`

Comment: Will it be possible to support codification of this in [phpDoc documentation](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/2019) and in [PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/issues/155)? Thanks

Comment: Not documented as Pavel said ( https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html ), you may end up with ParamNameNoMatch.

Comment: current @param documentation:  https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html#param
It's the end of 2021 and I still get `Doc comment for parameter &$val does not match actual variable name $val`